# VESTA using command line

Tags: density-functional-theory, crystallography, vesta, supercell

Can anyone please show me how to make a  supercell with VESTA
using a single command line without opening a GUI.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://jp-minerals.org/vesta/en/doc/VESTAch17.html#x36-23700017), but I am afraid that this is not possible with VESTA. You can use [Cif2Cell](https://github.com/kmu/cif2cell) if you do not mind to install one more package.

Comment: Please let us know if the solution by Camps works for you!

Comment: Thank you for the reply, the cif2cell works but the output is neither in cif nor poscar format.

Comment: You can use [Phonopy](https://phonopy.github.io/phonopy/vasp.html) to obtain supercell POSCAR file from a cif file: `phonopy -d --dim="3 3 3" -c yourFile.cif` should make a 3*3*3 supercell if `yourFile.cif` contains a unit cell cif

Comment: I recommend pymatgen or ASE for this. You can write a small Python script that reads the structure, calls their supercell functions, and writes to a file/stdout if you want to make the supercells with a single command.

Answer (score 3):

In line with the comments, I'm not sure if you can achieve this in VESTA, but a simple ASE or Pymatgen based script can easily do it. This is the Pymatgen script I use.

```
from pymatgen.core import Structure
from pymatgen.transformations.standard_transformations import SupercellTransformation
from sys import argv


assert len(argv) in [2, 4, 10]

struc = Structure.from_file('POSCAR')

if len(argv) == 2:
    st = SupercellTransformation.from_scaling_factors(argv[1], argv[1], argv[1])
elif len(argv) == 4:
    st = SupercellTransformation.from_scaling_factors(argv[1], argv[2], argv[3])
elif len(argv) == 10:
    scaling_matrix = [[argv[1], argv[2], argv[3]], [argv[4], argv[5], argv[6]],
                      [argv[7], argv[8], argv[9]]]
    st = SupercellTransformation(scaling_matrix)

super_struc = st.apply_transformation(struc)
super_struc.to('POSCAR_super')
```

This script assumes that there is a `POSCAR` file in the current directory and will make the necessary supercell depending on the command line arguments. For example,

- `python script.py 4` will make a $4 \times 4 \times 4$ supercell
- `python script.py 1 2 3` will make a $1 \times 2 \times 3$ supercell
- you can also just type out all 9 entries of the supercell matrix desired

This can easily be adapted for other file types, and be made an executable to be called conveniently from any directory (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27494758/how-do-i-make-a-python-script-executable)).